# How can I add the slot values dynamically from the result which we get through the api in the alexa skill

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am new in Alexa development. I am trying to create an Alexa skill with AWS lambda function and Node.js code. Its kind of trivia skill. I retrieve the questions from an api with their answers, I just want to put the answers in custom slot so that Alexa will recognise the user input and matching the answers will become easier. For now I have kept some answers in the custom slot. But thats not feasible solution as the number of questions and their answers may increase so putting each and every slot value is kind of difficult work. I have read about the Alexa’s behaviour and its NLP (natural language processing). Even if I put possible user inputs in the custom slot, we cannot predict whether Alexa will match the proper user input or not. So I need help in adding the slot values dynamically.

Comment: Why not simplify the user-input to a set of known responses. Most trivias are multiple choice with the answers being "A", "B", "C", or "D". You can expand that custom slot to include "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "last", etc.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, right now I have allowed the responses with "A", "B", "C", "D" only,  but is there any solution for getting dynamic values that I want to know..

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand then. Could you expand your question with an example of the Alexa interaction with user and what values from that example you want to put into slots?

Comment: do you really need to fill in all the slots values? per [this blog post](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx3IHSFQSUF3RQP/why-a-custom-slot-is-the-literal-solution), slot values are NOT a strict enum or array that limit what the user can say, so if you design the utterance correctly if should not be a problem, or perhapse you're looking for a [phrase slot](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/a2716002-0f50-4587-b038-31ce631c0c07/enhance-speech-recognition-of-your-alexa-skills-with-phrase-slots-and-amazon-searchquery) that will capture everything and verify inside your skill?

Comment: @user1 thank you this. I've been searching for a long time